# Unable to make calls after clean flash, mobile data working [LineageOS 14.1, Galaxy S7 SM-G930FD]

Tags: calls, lineageos, samsung-galaxy-s7

I just flashed the latest stable official Lineage ROM for S7 Duos (SM-G930FD), using the following process

1.Boot to TWRP recovery
2.Wipe everything except external SD (contains zips)
3. Add following to zip queue, flash, reboot.
lineage-14.1-20180419-nightly-herolte-signed.zip
open_gapps-arm64-7.1-micro-20180422
Magisk-v16.0.
4. Everything is working as expected, EXCEPT **I'm unable to make/receive calls or send SMS**.

The SIM is being detected with correct network, I can receive SMS and LTE data is working so it looks to be a software/config issue but I'm out of ideas, so would appreciate any pointers on what to check.